# Storing a hash as byte array with JPA

Tags: database, hibernate, jpa, hash, blob

My `User` entity class contains password hash field, which is a byte array with a fixed length (32 since it's an SHA-256 hash).

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Column(nullable=false)
    private byte[] passwordHash;
    ...
}
```

As you can see, I haven't annotated it with anything special, just a NOT NULL.

This works, but will it perform? My schema is generated by Hibernate, but I don't know exactly what it generates (I'm currently using an in-memory HSQL database).

I'm concerned that, since it doesn't know that it's a fixed length array (the `length` field of the `Column` annotation applies to strings only), it will store this hash in a BLOB field which is added in the record as a pointer (if I understand correctly how databases work).

Is this true, and how can I change this? Should I just encode the hash as a string, with base64 or hex, accepting the small performance/correctness impact of that?

Comment: Why don't you try it with the actual target database, and see what it generates?

Comment: @skaffman: I've changed the database to MySQL and it generates a TINYBLOB column

Comment: Although I suppose it doesn't *really* matter. I'm never going to index by password hash and I'll only ever need to read it for one record at a time. I'm still interested in making it perfect though, for academic purposes.

Answer (score 5):

> I'm concerned that, since it doesn't know that it's a fixed length array (the length field of the Column annotation applies to strings only), (...)

If you specify the column length, Hibernate will use this information to determine the SQL column type to generate (`TINYBLOB`, `BLOB`, `MEDIUMBLOB`, `LONGBLOB`) though.

> What I need is BINARY(32)

Did you try this?

```
@Column(columnDefinition="BINARY(32) NOT NULL")
private byte[] passwordHash;
```

Answer (score 1):

tinyblob is a good joice ([mysql types reference](http://help.scibit.com/mascon/masconMySQL_Field_Types.html)), but all my apps work fine with Strings.
If you really care about milli-seconds try both versions in a profiler and see what works best. My preferred profiler is the one included in netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, a SHA-256 hash is always only printable characters (and if not, encode it base64), so the solution is that you CAN store it as string, then use the `length` field of the `Column` annotation.

Then you've got your fixed length and no doubt about performance.

Comment: Nope, I've seen the output and it really consists mostly of unprintable characters (or rather isn't character data at all). I could of course base64 or hex encode it, but if I could store it in pure binary form, that would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be as efficient, but I suggest you use String as the storage type and translate as needed with the getter and setter methods.  This allows maximum portability for JPA between different databases.

I use a similar technique with Date/Time by storing longs that represent time since epoch in UTC which allows me to avoid timezone issues (timezone information is not portable in database dates across all databases).